# How Cloud Data Fusion connect to SAP NetWeaver Gateway and SAP BW/4HANA

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, sap-gateway, sap-bw

I've been searching SAP NetWeaver Gateway and SAP BW/4HANA connector in Cloud Data Fusion "HUB" on the top right of console but I can't find any. How can I connect to those SAP NetWeaver Gateway and SAP BW/4HANA if it doesn't appear in the "HUB".

Answer (score 0):

CDF has currently plugins for SAP via SAP Application Server: SAP Table (table extraction with optional filter) and SAP ODP (full and delta extraction from ERP Datasources). You can currently use the existing SAP Table plugin to read from application tables in BW4HANA, eg. tables /BIC/OH.... underlying OHDs